# Apex repeat to manipulate data in list not working

Tags: controller, repeat

I am using apex: repeat tag to repeat data in a textbox. I have a custom setting on the vf page and a number field. I want to concatenate both in a textfield. And repeat the concatenated values again and again whenever the user selects the custom setting and puts any value in the number field.
Can someone please help me with this?

---

Visualforce copied from comment:

```
<apex:selectList value="{!Other__c.Type__c}" label="Type" size="1">
    <apex:actionsupport event="onchange" action="{!chang}" />
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!type1}" >
    </apex:selectOptions>
</apex:selectList>
<apex:inputfield value="{!Other__c.no_of_items__c}"/>
<apex:repeat value="{!ms1}" var="line">
    Term
    <apex:outputField value="{!ms1.Term__c}"/>
    <br/>
    <apex:outputText value="{!termdefined}"/>
    Overall
    <apex:outputText value="{!doppl}"/>
</apex:repeat>
```

Code copied from comment:

```
public list<Other__c> ms1 = new list<Other__c>();
public String doppl{get;set;}
public string termdefined{set;get;}

public Otherclass1(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    list<Other__c> ms1 = [select id, Type__c,no_of_items__c from Other__c];
    this.Other__c= ms1[0];
    doppl=ms1.Term__c;
}

public List<selectoption> gettype1(){
    type.clear();
    ser=[select id,name from service__c];
    for( service__c m:ser ){
        type.add(new selectoption(m.name,m.name));
    }
    return type ;
}

public string termdefined(){
    doppl=ms1.Type__c+ '(' + ms1.no_of_items__c + ')';
    return doppl;
}
```

Copied from comment:

`Type__c` is the custom setting, `No_of_items__c` is the number field, `Term__c` is the text field where I need to concatenate type and number of items everytime the user chooses any type and its no of items. It should be stored in `Term` field.

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: <apex:selectList value="{!Other__c.Type__c}" label="Type" size="1">
<apex:actionsupport event="onchange" action="{!chang}" />
 <apex:selectOptions value="{!type1}"  >
</apex:selectOptions>
  </apex:selectList>
<apex:inputfield value="{!Other__c.no_of_items__c}"/>
<apex:repeat value="{!ms1}" var="line">
 Term <apex:outputField value="{!ms1.Term__c}"/> <br/>
 <apex:outputText value="{!termdefined}"/>
    Overall <apex:outputText value="{!doppl}"/>
</apex:repeat>

Comment: public list<Other__c> ms1 = new list<Other__c>();
public String doppl{get;set;}
public string termdefined{set;get;}
public Otherclass1(ApexPages.StandardController controller) { list<Other__c> ms1 = [select id, Type__c,no_of_items__c from Other__c];
this.Other__c= ms1[0];  
doppl=ms1.Term__c;}
public List<selectoption> gettype1(){
type.clear();
ser=[select id,name from service__c];
for( service__c m:ser ){
type.add(new selectoption(m.name,m.name));
}
return type ; }  
public string termdefined(){
doppl=ms1.Type__c+ '(' + ms1.no_of_items__c + ')';
return doppl;  
}

Comment: Type__c is the custom setting, No_of_items__c is the number field,Term__c is the text field where I need to concatenate type and number of items everytime the user chooses any type and its no of items. It should be stored in Term field

Comment: Woah. Please edit your question and add the code with the code formatting please. This is a little difficult to read :)

Comment: Do you want your page to edit just one Other__c object (the standard controller one) and just show all the Other__c objects for reference? Or do you want to display a table where all of the Other__c objects are editable?

Answer (score 1):

Ok. You haven't mentioned the exact error you're facing so I'm going to point out a couple of things in your code which might be causing issues:

```
//You seem to be calling the custom setting 'Type__c' from the object 'Other__c'?
//A custom setting is independent and not a lookup field in an object
list<Other__c> ms1 = [select id, Type__c,no_of_items__c from Other__c];

//I think you meant to create an object of Other__c--> Other__c oc=ms1[0]
this.Other__c= ms1[0];

//You are not calling the field Term__c in your query
doppl=ms1.Term__c;
```

The second method:

```
type.clear();//type not defined

ser=[select id,name from service__c];//ser not defined

for( service__c m:ser ){
    type.add(new selectoption(m.name,m.name));//type not defined
}
return type ;
```

Start with these changes, then come back with any further errors, I'll edit my post accordingly